# Clean Data in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, data-analysis

i need help on cleaning this data. Currently I've no idea to clean this kind of data. I want to clean based on month and total per supplier. Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Select the first 2 columns [No] and [Supplier]
2. On the tab `Transform` drop down `Unpivot Columns` and click on `Unpipot Other Columns`

This converts your wide pivot table into a long, stacked format that is ideal for further processing.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Another way you can achieve this is

1. Select all the date columns.
2. Click on the **transform** tab, under any column section, click on **unpivot only selected columns**
3. Kindly rename the Attribute column to date

If you need to split the date column into month and year
4. on the **transform** tab, under the text column section, click on **Split Column**, select "by delimiter" on the dialog box, select split at the left-most delimiter and click ok.

You will have your month and year columns as shown below [image]

if your value column holds figure for amount/money you can transform the data type and replace the null values with zero using the replace values function when you right-click on the values column.

I hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your help! it helps me a lot in learning data transformation :)